# how to check for variable existence in array key php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array which has variables for key values:

```
$first = array($h0=>array(),$h1=>array(),$h2=>array(),$h3=>array(),$h4=>array(),$h5=>array(),$h6=>array (),$h7=>array(),$h8=>array(),$h9=>array());
unset($first[null]);
```

The problem is that some of those variables may not have been created, thus making "undefined variable" errors pop up on the screen. So I tried this:

```
$first= array($h0=>array(),isset($h1)=>array(),isset($h2)=>array(),isset($h3)=>array(),isset($h4)=>array(),isset($h5)=>array(),isset($h6)=>array(),isset($h7)=>array(),isset($h8)=>array(),isset($h9)=>array());
unset($first[null]);
```

That didn't work... at all. I don't just want to turn off error reporting, as that would be the improper way around it. What is the correct way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the values of `$h0, $h1` etc are, where they come from and what you're trying to do... but to check if a variable is set you can use `isset()`.

```
if( isset( $array[ 'key'] ) )
{
    // $array['key'] is set
}

if( isset( $variable ) )
{
   // $variable is set
}
```

Looking at your code I'd imagine you want something like this, but it's quite difficult to tell from your question, you need to check the keys are set before adding them to the array.

```
$first = array();

if( isset( $h0 ) )
{
    $first[ $h0 ] = array();
}

if( isset( $h1 ) )
{
    $first[ $h1 ] = array();
}
```

Depending on exactly what you're trying to do, instead of a load of if statements it might be better to use a loop.